# Regex: Exclude match

Tags: php, regex

I have this pattern:

`~^([a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]+)(\.[a-z]+)?)$~i`

It will match the following:

`xxx.xxx` or
`xxx.xxx.xxx`

(number of x per doesn't matter)

How do I disallow `xxx.xxx.xxx` if the set of characters before the first `.` is `wwww` ?

For example, it should allow `example.co` or `example.co.uk` but it should not allow `www.example.co` or `www.example.co.uk`

Comment: It's called a 'negative lookbehind'. "find X as long as Y isn't in front of it": http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now so I won't add a new answer, but try with a negative look-behind assertion: `(?<!www)`. Place it just after the `^`.

Comment: You might want to test the regex with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead/lookbehind, eg:

```
~^((?!www\.)[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]+[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]+)(\.[a-z]+)?)$~i
```